# Set combobox with second column

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a combobox with two columns, description and ID respectively. The ID column is hidden. Sometimes the combobox value is selected programatically, I would like to be able to make this selection using the ID column. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ID column is the bound column, you can simply say:

```
 Me.MyCombo=1
```

Where 1 is an ID in the row source.

Comment: I should have know it was something simple like that. Thanks!